# How to prioritize asynchronous tasks in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

This came up in the context of an app that runs some relatively costly computations in a web worker, and has to prioritize some of these computations over others (for example those affecting the UI over those needed to sync data with the server).

As a simple example, suppose I have some observables that asynchronously process values emitted by a source observable:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, share } from 'rxjs/operators';

const a = interval(500).pipe(share());

const b = a.pipe(delay(0), map(value => value + 10));

const c = b.pipe(delay(0), map(value => value + 100));

const d = a.pipe(delay(0), map(value => value + 1000));
```

I would like the values to be processed in a specific order, for example `a`, `b`, `d`, `c`, so `b` has priority over `d`, and `d` over `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [concat](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat)

```
const result = concat(a, b, d, c)
```